# vapor can not load html and leaf

Tags: swift, vapor

I use vapor load a html or leaf,it gives me error message '500'.The server log show me

```
[Data File Error: unable to load file at path /Users/apple/Desktop/QSSwiftServer/Resources/Views/welcome.leaf]  
 [Identifier: Core.DataFileError.load]  

[Possible Causes: file doesn't exist, missing read permissions at specified path, data read is corrupted, system issue]  

[Suggested Fixes: ensure that file permissions are correct for specified paths]  

[Documentation Links: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager]
```

Here is my code:

```
get { req in
        return try self.view.make("welcome.leaf", ["message": "Hello world!"])
    }
```

How can I solve this problem？

Comment: @CalebKleveter I faced the same error. Could you explain more detail?

Comment: @lee I don't have enough information to answer this question. I need to know things such as what the actual path to the file is, its permissions, and other such things.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your file into `{Project Dir}/Resources/Views/`

In your case `welcome.leaf` should be in `/Users/apple/Desktop/QSSwiftServer/Resources/Views/`